# Resort SortedList when list items change

Tags: javafx, java-8, sortedlist

I have this code:

```
table = initTable(); // TableView<Row>
list = initList(); // ObservableList<Row>
slist = new SortedList<>(list, (r1, r2) -> {
    return Integer.compare(r1.id.get(), r2.id.get());
});
table.setItems(slist);
```

When I add a new row to list, sorting works perfect.
But how to do resorting list when some row changes, for example:

```
Row row = getSomeRowFromList();
row.setNewId(100);
```

I need to resort after this code. I found only one solution It's reinit list inside the tableview:

```
table.setItems(list);
FXCollections.sort(table.getItems(), (r1, r2) -> {
    return -Integer.compare(r1.id.get(), r2.id.get());
});
```

It seems wrong, how to force resorting list, after I change some items?

Comment: I need create list, with Observable: FXCollections.observableArrayList((Row c) -> new Observable[]{ c.id });

Comment: More likely with `FXCollections.observableArrayList(c -> new Observable[] {c.idProperty()});` (since `id` should be `private`) but yes, that's the idea.